# Swift protocol extension with default implementation used in objective c

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have a protocol UnmutePrompt with default implementation for onTurnUpVolumePressed  and want to convert it @objc to enable objective c class conform to , but I couldn't as default implementation is not supported in objective c

```
public protocol UnmutePrompt {
    var onTurnUpVolumePressed: (() -> Void) { set get }
}

extension UnmutePrompt {
    // Default implementation for `onTurnUpVolumePressed`
    public var onTurnUpVolumePressed: (() -> Void) {
        get {
            return onTurnUpVolumePressedDefaultImplementation
        }
        set {}
    }
    
    private func onTurnUpVolumePressedDefaultImplementation() {
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.changeVolume(value: Constants.minThreshold)
    }
}
```